# OAuth.io Caching on iOS

Tags: ios, caching, swift, oauth

The OAuth.io modal dialog shows up every time I call it, even if I setup the caching option ([see: using the cache here](https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios)). Here is a code snippet from my Swift-based application:

```
let options = NSMutableDictionary()
options.setObject("true" as NSString, forKey: "cache")
let oauthModal: OAuthIOModal = OAuthIOModal(key: config?.valueForKey("oauth_key") as String!, delegate: self, andOptions: options)
if (!oauthModal.cacheAvailableForProvider(self.provider)) {
    oauthModal.showWithProvider(self.provider)
}
```

The dialog shows up just fine, and I am able to go through the whole flow, but cacheAvailableForProvider never returns true. I confirmed that my app is able to create files in the caches directory, but after running it in the simulator, I never see an oauthio-provider.json file get created.

NOTE: the second time the dialog pops up, Safari does remember my login to the provider, but I was under the impression that caching was supposed to stop the dialog from popping up all together.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello,
Everything seems to be configured properly. We have tested the latest version of the SDK with an objective C app and everything seems to work normally. However we have not tested the SDK with swift yet. We're going to investigate the problem, and will come back to you asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your code, I realized that you gave the `options` dictionary containing the cache field to the OAuthIOModal constructor.

You should give this dictionary to the `oauthModal.showWithProvider` method, like this:

```
modal.showWithProvider(self.provider, options:options)
```

Hope this will help you

Have a nice day.

Comment: Strange, I am still getting the popup every time. Here is my new code:
`let options = NSMutableDictionary()`

`options.setObject("true", forKey: "cache")`

`oauthModal.showWithProvider(self.provider, options: options)`

Comment: Another update, I was able to confirm that the oauthio-provider.json file is getting created on the file system...no idea why it isn't picking it up the second time. The content of the json file looks legit.

Comment: Also, it seems that cacheAvailableForProvider is returning true, but alas, when I call showWithProvider, even after cacheAvailableForProvider returns true, the dreaded popup :(

Comment: I think I see the issue. OAuthIOModal.m line 356: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios/blob/master/OAuthiOS/Src/OAuthIOModal.m

You are only using the cache if expires is after now, where expires is the date starting at 1970 with the value of "expires" added to it. The problem is, the provider I am using (fitbit) does not appear to be setting expires, as that key is missing from the json - which presumably  make the expiration date 1970...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, we'll check it again with Fitbit and come back to you.

Comment: We have published the 1.2.1 version of the SDK, which adds a default expiring date for provides that don't return one already. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Okay, after connecting several hours ago, and verifying that the cache was working, I am now getting an error back from fitbit when the modal uses the cached credentials:
401 | oauth | oauth_access_token | Invalid signature <signature_value> or token <token_value> | when just "client" validation is required but signature does not match and access token provided"
Does this mean my credentials have expired? If I clear the OAuthIOModal cache and re-authenticate, I no longer get the error, but it kind of defeats the purpose of caching if it only lasts for a few hours...

Comment: After further testing, this issue may be due to the fact that I was authenticating with my Fitbit account on multiple devices, which invalidates the cache on the other devices (probably to be expected)