# Cache OAuth information so user does not need to re-login

Tags: android, popup, oauth.io

I am trying to implement oAuth.io on android and I want it so that the user doesn't have to login every single time. How can I cache the request object?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this today, and I think I've come to the conclusion that contrary to their documentation, 'cache' is not a valid option for their OAuth popup in Android.

http://docs.oauth.io/?Android#authorize-with-a-popup

This documentation says 'cache' is a valid option, which you include as the 2nd argument for OAuth.popup() in a JSON object.

But I've looked through the source on their GitHub, and on OAuth.popup() the below is specified, with no mention of cache as an option. The rest of the code doesn't seem to recognize it as an option.

> @param opts A JSONObject containing additional options.
>   It can contain an "authorize" JSONObject with additional query parameters
>   to pass to the authorize url.

It may also be relevant to you, but looking at this question about iOS caching:

[OAuth.io Caching on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612838/oauth-io-caching-on-ios)

In the comments on the accepted answer, it shows that some providers like Fitbit (which I'm attempting to get to work) don't provide an "expires_in" attribute, and OAuth.io's implementation didn't account for that so caching immediately expired. I thought that would be the problem here, but it's looking like the cache option doesn't exist at all in Android with no future indicators. I'm not sure what I'll do about that at this point, but I'm not that impressed by their misleading documentation.